# ActiveRecord::Relation has objects with nil ids and why other data is not selected

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `events` table, from which I just want to select specific formatted data, that do not directly relate the Event model.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DATE(MIN(schedule)) as schedule_date 
FROM `events`  
WHERE (`events`.`state` IN (1)) 
GROUP BY YEAR(schedule), MONTH(schedule)
```

I do it this this way:

```
Event.select("DATE(MIN(schedule)) as schedule_date").
with_state(:published).
group("YEAR(schedule)").group("MONTH(schedule)")
```

As a result I want to receive the array of elements like `['2014-01-02', '2014-03-08', ...]`, but instead I receive an ActiveRecord::Relation object like this:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, #<Event id: nil>, ...]>
```

This object does not contain IDs of events (but this is what I want, actually). At the same time it does not have `schedule_date` data (this is not what is want: I need only this data and nothing more).

**So my question:**

Where should I put methods like this? I'm not sure that in my case the Event model is the right place for it (I'm new to Rails), but is will be reused multiple times in different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get data I need (and nothing more), at first I decided to do like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("
  SELECT DATE(MIN(`schedule`)) AS `schedule_date` 
  FROM `events` 
  WHERE `events`.`state` = 1 
  GROUP BY YEAR(`schedule`), MONTH(`schedule`) 
  ORDER BY `schedule_date` DESC")
```

But this approach is too ugly to use :( So I was told that better approach is to use arel for my purpose and I ended up with the following code:

```
module EventService
  extend self

  def first_monthly_dates
    schedule_column = Event.arel_table[:schedule]
    Event.
      with_state(:published).
      group(schedule_column.extract(:year)).
      group(schedule_column.extract(:month)).
      order(schedule_column.desc).
      select(schedule_column.minimum.as('schedule'))
  end
end
```

As a result you'll get something like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: nil, schedule: "2014-03-05 03:09:00">, #<Event id: nil, schedule: "2014-04-18 14:40:00">, #<Event id: nil, schedule: "2014-06-11 05:02:00">, #<Event id: nil, schedule: "2014-07-06 05:24:00">,
```

This is the answer to my question: if you have some method that somehow relates to your model but is not bound to it, it is better to create separate service and move the code to separate module.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
dates = Event.with_state(:published).all.map(&:schedule)
```

This will give you all the `schedule` fields from the events

```
dates.uniq!
```

Will allow to get only the uniq values

Comment: That is not what I've asked. And your code produces wrong SQL - I wrote what SQL I need exactly.